# How to open a text file as dict in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

i have a question. These are the first few lines of the large text.txt file that i have: https://pastebin.com/UV7UiU5M and i would need to open it as a dict to iterate it,, and get the values. I tried with

```
for line in open('/home/conacons/Documents/products_with_stocks.txt'):
    name = line.split()
    for i in name[0:2]:
        print i
```

and i get:

```
{
'BranchId':
'1',
 'ArticleId':
'50375476',
'EAN':
 '4029044771246',
  'Price':
 Decimal('299.95000'),
 'Stock':
  Decimal('1.00000'),
    'ReservedStock':
 Decimal('0'),
 'LastMove':
 datetime.datetime(2017,
 },
```

but its not iterable, i cannot use the values.

EDIT:

I got a piece of the code to write the file. It looks like this:

```
for n in range(0,650): 
    req['IterationConstraints']['BlockIndex'] = n 
    articles =   client.service.GetArticles(req) 
    f.write(str(articles))
```

Comment: just a thought, maybe the `eval` function works if you take that input as a string.

Comment: What is the source of this text file? You should have *serialized* your data using some sort of existing, supported format, such as `JSON` or `pickle`. Instead, it looks like someone dumped the pretty-printed output of some nested `dict` to a text file. That is *not what you should do*. Hacking together some solution is pretty straightforward with `eval`, but you shouldn't be in this position in the first place, but you'll have to `import` the right types into the global namespace, like `Decimal` and `datetime.datetime`

Comment: there is also a `json decoder` that you can check, since the format you are trying to read seems to be a json

Comment: @silgon it is **definitely not JSON**. Note the single-quotes and the `Decimal` and `datetime.datetime` objects.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you're right, I check the document really fast, in that case the evaluation of the file as a string should work.

Comment: @silgon as long as `Decimal` and `datetime.datetime` are in the namespace

Comment: `datetime.datetime(2017,` ...  seems like the dump has unbalanced parentheses as well...

Comment: If you could get whatever code generates that file to spit out a proper JSON, then you could just load it as a json directly from the file. In absence of that you need to write your own parser which will probably break whenever the file structure changes.

Comment: Is `client.service.GetArticles(req)` not available to you in the process you're trying to read this back in to? Seems a bit of a waste to transport the data out, then transport it back in if not required...

Comment: well my colleague got the info in the text file, waited for the script to finish for almost a week, there are like 3 million lines in the file. So now i would waste another week if a call the webservice again... thats why i need to iterate this file

Comment: Write your own parser then that splits it into individual strings (suggest to use the "}{" line to split them) and then eval each of them into a list of python dicts that you can then parse

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a valid json your datetime is wrong :

{
'BranchId':
'1',
 'ArticleId':
'50375476',
'EAN':
 '4029044771246',
  'Price':
 Decimal('299.95000'),
 'Stock':
  Decimal('1.00000'),
    'ReservedStock':
 Decimal('0'),
 'LastMove':
 datetime.datetime(2017,12,12)
 }

then, with the following script i could evaluate file as a dict:

```
import datetime
from decimal import Decimal

with open('file2.txt') as json_file:
    eval(json_file.read())

#{'ReservedStock': Decimal('0'), 'EAN': '4029044771246', 'Price': Decimal('299.95000'), 'BranchId': '1', 'LastMove': datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 12, 0, 0), 'ArticleId': '50375476', 'Stock': Decimal('1.00000')}
```

You need model your file as a json or a list of json if you want to eval it. In this [paste](https://pastebin.com/6WfegFw6) you have the file with the correct format

Comment: my file is valid, the one with the missing datetime was my wrong output from the test-iteration (not-successful either). So now i tried your code from above and get:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/looping_futura_stocks.py", line 11, in <module>
    i = eval(json_file.read())
  File "<string>", line 31
    }{
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: as i said, if you have a list of dict, you need modeling  it as a list. [{'a':1},{'a':2}], you format is  now, a valid dict separated, but all together are not a valid list of dict.

Comment: so how should i proceed?

Comment: This is not a json file.

Comment: You should separate by comma your dicts and place into a list [ ]. I know that it isnt a json file but is a format you can evaluate in python.

Answer (score -2):

Try adding a name to your dict in the .txt file... Then you can rename the file with os.rename() zu doesnt_matter.py and then you can do from doesnt_matter import dictname